# Conditionally Adding Attribute Directive to an element but also passing an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

- I am trying to write an attribute type directive.
- I also want this attribute type directive to be added conditionally.
- I also want to pass an object to this directive.

This is what I am so far:

js

```
.directive('autocompleteDirective', ['$timeout', function (timeout) {
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        templateUrl: currentScriptPath.replace('.js', '.html'),
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            el.autocomplete({
                source: scope.model,
                select: function () {
                    timeout(function () {
                        el.trigger('input');
                    },0)
                }
            });
        },
        scope: {
            model: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

html

```
<textarea ng-attr-autocomplete-directive="{{param.autocomplete}}" ng-switch-when="textarea" ng-model="param.value" validator="{{param.validator || 'empty'}}" />
```

i want something like or better than

```
<textarea ng-attr-autocomplete-directive="{{shouldadd? param.autocomplete:false}}" ng-switch-when="textarea" ng-model="param.value" validator="{{param.validator || 'empty'}}" />
```

Comment: Explain *"add conditionally"* in more detail. Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: Sir, 'add conditionally' means that sometimes this directive will not be the part of html and sometimes it will, on the basis of a boolean variable named 'shouldadd', therefore i am trying to add this directive using ng-attr-{{directivename}}. I want to pass the value of param.autocomplete object into this directive?